# Как методом интерполяции можно заполнить недостающие значения в колонке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scipy, интерполяция

Как методом интерполяции можно заполнить недостающие значения в колонке `"Production rate"`, какие есть варианты?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2010-01-10', '2010-01-09', '2010-01-08', 
                            '2010-01-07', '2010-01-06', '2010-01-05',
                            '2010-01-04', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-02', 
                            '2010-01-01'], 
        'Production rate': 
         [58.6, "nan", 60.1, 39.7, "nan", "nan", 57.7, 58.2, 58.6, "nan"]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.interpolate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df["Production rate"] = \
    pd.to_numeric(df["Production rate"], errors="coerce").interpolate()
```

результат:

```
In [357]: df
Out[357]:
         Date  Production rate
0  2010-01-10            58.60
1  2010-01-09            59.35
2  2010-01-08            60.10
3  2010-01-07            39.70
4  2010-01-06            45.70
5  2010-01-05            51.70
6  2010-01-04            57.70
7  2010-01-03            58.20
8  2010-01-02            58.60
9  2010-01-01            58.60
```